# unable to select dropdown option after updating jar files to selenium 3.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code after updating  the new `selenium 3.0 beta` jar files. However in earlier version of selenium it was working perfectly.

I updated as it was giving error :

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with index: 1
>
> For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'GUR-ITD-8C', ip: '172.21.45.117', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

```
expedia.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
Select LineOfBusiness = new Select(expedia.findElement(By.id("lineOfBusiness")));
LineOfBusiness.selectByIndex(1);
Assert.assertEquals(LineOfBusiness.getFirstSelectedOption().getText(), "HWW Sales");
```

Comment: Share you dropdown HTML as well?? try to print the option size as `System.out.println(LineOfBusiness .getOptions().size());` and let us know the result..:)

Comment: <select id="lineOfBusiness" class="w420p h40p bdrno" onchange="ShowHideETE(-1);" name="lineOfBusiness">
<option value="">Select line of business</option>
<option value="1">HWW Sales</option>
<option value="2">EAN Sales</option>
<option value="4">HWW Email</option>
<option value="5">A2A Email</option>
<option value="6">A2A Phone</option>
<option value="7">CDS Email</option>
<option value="8">CDS Phone</option>
<option value="9">A2A Follow-up Team</option>
<option value="10">CDS Follow-up Team</option>
</select>

Comment: What is the output for this `System.out.println(LineOfBusiness.getOptions().size());`??

Comment: Did you tried to select option using visible text as `LineOfBusiness.selectByVisibleText("HWW Sales");`??

Comment: I used System.out.println(LineOfBusiness .getOptions().size());
It shows the size in Console 10 but with same error

Comment: try using this `LineOfBusiness.selectByVisibleText("HWW Sales");` and let me know..:)

Comment: Yesy I tried all the options also tried select by value

Comment: So when are you using `selectByVisibleText` what is the exception occurred??

Comment: I get this error : java.lang.AssertionError: expected [HWW Sales] but found [Select line of business]

Comment: but this assertion error, plsease make sure first `selectByVisibleText` selects desire option or not??

Comment: It was working fine beore I updated to Selenium 3.0 beta. and I updated because it was giving error while I was running the program.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue in your case, but if you want an aleternate solution try using `JavascriptExecutor`. see provided answer and let me know..:)

Comment: Try adding a click on the select drop-down and the go for selectByIndex or selectBy VisibleText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the issue in your case using `Select` class, but if you want an alternate solution to get rid from this error, you can try using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
public static String selectByIndex(WebDriver driver, WebElement select, int index) {

        String javaScript = "var select = arguments[0]; "
                + "select.options[arguments[1]].selected = true;"
                + "return select.selectedOptions[0].text";

        return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScript, select, index);   
}


WebElement select = expedia.findElement(By.id("lineOfBusiness"));

Assert.assertEquals(selectByIndex(expedia, select, 1), "HWW Sales");
```

Comment: It works for me thanks but I think it will for the lineOfBusiness only if I have to select others then have to use more JavascriptExecutor. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you can consider it if nothing works because using javascript is not good for actual automation user testing but you can take it as an option if nothing works to go ahead..thanks..:)

Comment: Thanks for your help.Yeah I understand that I will work to resolve the error for a while I will use javascriptexecutor

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//* 
 [@id='App']/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/select"));

 List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

for (WebElement option : allOptions)
{
    if (examboard.equals("Select") && option.getText().equals("Select") )
    {
        new Select(By.xpath("//select").findElement(driver)).selectByVisibleText(allOptions.get(0).getText());
        System.out.println("Name of the exam board is -->" + examboard);
        Utils.waitForElement(1000);
    }
}
```