# Selenium: Cannot select item from dropdown box

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am using Selenium 3 with Firefox 48 on Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I want to automatically select an item from a dropdown box but it always fails.

Here is my approach:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

(new Main()).doit();

}

void doit() {
String geckoPath = "/opt/geckodriver"; // System dependent
String baseUrl = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select";

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoPath);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get(baseUrl);

// convinience click to scroll near dropdown box
driver.findElement(By.id("Result")).click();

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.name("select"));
//elem.click(); // verify we have the right element
Select dropdown = new Select(elem);

System.out.println("Selected option (before): " + dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());

synchronized (this) {
    try {
        wait(2000); // redundant; just to be safe we are not too fast
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

//dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Value 3");
dropdown.selectByValue("value3");
System.out.println("Selected option (after): " + dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());

return;
}


}
```

The element is corretly identified, as can be determined by uncommenting the `//elem.click()` line. However, the selection never happens. It does not matter which function I try, `selectByVisibleText("Value 3")` or `selectByValue("value3")`.

It maybe a bug in Selenium framework, since it is still in beta, but I am not sure about that. If it is in fact a bug then I would appreciate it if someone could share a link to Selenium 2 binaries. I tried downloading Selenium 2 from Github but the build failed. It is also quite poorly documented, so I am not sure what to do with the binaries once compiled. The Selenium 3 framework had some 3rd party binaries that I did not see in Selenium 2. Not sure whether I would have to download them elsewhere or they are just not needed.

PS: If you want to try the above example then you will have to change the path to your gecko-driver.

Comment: You can consider this option for now using `JavascriptExecutor`..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224373/unable-to-select-dropdown-option-after-updating-jar-files-to-selenium-3-0/39228389#39228389

Comment: You might have to wait for the element to be present/visible/clickable before performing a click. Use like this: `webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem));`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes, that worked fine. Thanks.