# Not able to select a dropdown in firefox browser for selenium version 3.0.0-beta2

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm not able to select any dropdown in firefox browser when using `selenium 3 beta 2`. I'm getting :

> element not visible exception

Here are some more details:

[image: Browser Page]

StackError:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not visible (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
>   System info: host: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20160817112116, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=48.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
>   Session ID: 1bdaa5b9-a2b8-47aa-81b8-5516c39462a7
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:683)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:319)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.setSelected(Select.java:324)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByValue(Select.java:201)
>       at DriverTest.test(DriverTest.java:45)

While for chrome browser, it is perfectly working fine.

I think there is some issue with firefox browser. Currently i can see that firefox can be updated to `48.0.2`. Do we have a fix for this yet?

Comment: Could you share your code which have you tried??

Comment: The problem is with Firefox browser. For chrome it's working fine. new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country"))).selectByVisibleText("India");

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224373/unable-to-select-dropdown-option-after-updating-jar-files-to-selenium-3-0/39228389#39228389.. hope it helps..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Thanks Saurabh for the redirection to alternate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebDriverWait if you are not using it.With WebDriverWait the code should be like

```
Select sel = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("country"))));
    sel.selectByVisibleText("Albania");
```

Comment: new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country"))).selectByVisibleText("India"); \n My above code works with Chrome but not with Firefox...i think this is a issue with Firefox and selenium 3 beta 2