# Select drop down is not working in firefox 48 using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am using Selenium 3.0 and firefox 48 to automate the application. But in firefox48, automate to select drop down is not working.

The same code is working fine for IE and chrome.

Is this issue with the browser or my code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQHAZ.png)

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'BusinessUnit')]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_vmsContent_rdwBusinessUnit_C_selBusinessUnit")));
List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();
for (WebElement el : list)
{
    System.out.println(el.getText());
    sel.selectByIndex(2);
}
```

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224373/unable-to-select-dropdown-option-after-updating-jar-files-to-selenium-3-0/39228389#39228389

Comment: @naveen, are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

I would streamline the code a little. I added a little code for debugging purposes.

```
// wait until returns a WebElement, store it for later use
WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'BusinessUnit')]")));
// dump the HTML of the select element and make sure you have the element you are expecting
System.out.println(e.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
Select sel = new Select(e);
for (WebElement el : sel.getOptions())
{
    System.out.println(el.getText());
}
sel.selectByIndex(2); // pull this out of the loop or it will get selected mutliple times
// other options for selecting the desired OPTION
sel.selectByValue("12");
sel.selectByVisibleText("Engineering");
```

Comment: You got any solution ?

Comment: @HemaSundar Sure, in my answer above. I'm confused what you are asking.